# For a group $G$, show the relation $x\sim y$ defined by $\exists a(y=axa^{-1})$ is an equivalence relation on $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, equivalence-relations

Let G be a group. For $x,y\in G$, define $x\sim y$ if there exists some element $a\in G$ such that $y=axa^{-1}$. Show that ~ defines an equivalence relation on $G$.

Comment: aaaand what have you tried :')?

Comment: Reflexive: Suppose a∈G where y=axa^-1. Now if a=1, then y=x. Hence x~x. I am pretty sure there is something wrong here.

Comment: There you go. Now try to prove that the relation is reflexive. If $y=axa^{-1}$, can you show that for some $b$, you have the equation $x=byb^{-1}$?

Comment: Do you mean symmetric? Suppose b∈G where x=bab^-1. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean $x=byb^{-1}$. And no, you cannot suppose you have such a $b$. If you suppose $x\equiv y$, you must PROVE that $y\equiv x$. This is done by assuming that you have such an $a\in G$ that $y=axa^{-1}$ and then finding such a $b\in G$ that $x=byb^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$x \sim x$

$a:=e$ satisfies the condition.

$x \sim y \implies y \sim x$

Suppose $x \sim y$. Then there exists an $a$ such that $y=axa^{-1}$. Rearranging the equation:
$$a^{-1}ya=x$$
Recall that for an arbitrary group and an element $x$ in the group $(x^{-1})^{-1}=x$. Thus  $a^{-1}$ satisfies the condition.

$x \sim y \wedge y \sim z \implies x \sim z$

Suppose $x \sim y$ and $y \sim z$. Then there exist $a,b$ such that:
$$x=aya^{-1} \space \space \space (1)$$
$$y=bzb^{-1}$$
From equation (1) we have:
$$y=a^{-1}xa$$
$$a^{-1}xa=bzb^{-1}$$
$$b^{-1}a^{-1}xab=z$$
Recall that in an arbitrary group all elements $x,y$ satisfy $(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}$

So $ab$ indeed satisfies the condition.
This concludes the proof.